# PWM issues with pigpio and RPi.GPIO

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, pwm, pigpio

I am using Pi Zero W with latest Raspberry Pi OS.

I have a backlight of an LCD that I am trying to control via PWM.

If I use RPi.GPIO I get flicker at anything other that 100% (or 0%) duty cycle.  As I understand, this is probably due to the timing of the software PWM being affected by other processes.

If I use pigpio, I get good dimming but as soon as I turn the backlight off and back on, it breaks the dimming and I only get full-on or off.  Only a reboot fixes this.

The backlight goes off even if I set the DC to `1` (/255) not only to zero , which is also strange and in either case, as mentioned, it breaks the dimming until reboot.

The backlight also automatically comes on as I have it in an overlay for the screen, here is the extract from the dts file.  If I comment out that fragment, then I get no dimming at all, just on/off from the start. Also, `default-off` doesn't change anything.

```
    fragment@5 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            rpi_backlight: rpi_backlight {
                compatible = "gpio-backlight";
                gpios = <&gpio 18 0>;
                default-on;
            };
        };
    };
```

Ideally, I would remove that fragment and only control the backlight from Python and ideally without a daemon consuming resources.

1. How can I fix pigpio so that I can turn the backlight off and then get it dimming again (ideally without DTS fragment above or with it defaulting to off)?
2. pigpio daemon is going to continually use resources just for a backlight, is there a fix for RPi.GPIO so that I can use the hardware PWM (since I am using GPIO 18 which has that capability, as I understand) - also ideally without `fragment@5`

**Edit:**
This is the python script that dims the backlight up and down.

```
$ sudo pigpiod
$ python3
import pigpio
import time
gpio = pigpio.pi()
gpio.set_mode(18, pigpio.OUTPUT)
#gpio.set_mode(18, pigpio.ALT5) - behaves the same

def dim_up():
    for x in range(2,200):
        gpio.set_PWM_dutycycle(18, x)
        print('level =', x)
        time.sleep(0.01)

def dim_down():
    for x in range(200,1,-1):
        gpio.set_PWM_dutycycle(18, x)
        print('level =', x)
        time.sleep(0.01)

def cycle_dim():
    while True:
        dim_up()
        dim_down()

cycle_dim()
```

This works fine and dims up and down smoothly until you change either `range` to include `1` or `0` in the range.  Then, the first time before it hits those numbers, it works fine, then after those numbers it is either full on or full off, no range in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the way PWM was interfacing with the Texas Instruments TPS61165 LED driver which made it switch control modes to EasyScale.  As Joan kindly pointed out, increasing the PWM frequency to 1m stopped this from happening and provided reliable dimming.

Answer (score 0):

The dtb fragment is irrelevant to pigpio.  It makes no use of the fragment.

With pigpio you can use any expansion header GPIO to generate flicker free PWM suitable for LEDs.  You can easily check by using the `pigs` utility from the command line.

e.g. for GPIO 18 use e.g. `pigs p 18 x`, for GPIO 5 use `pigs p 5 x` etc.  Where x is 0 for off, 255 for fully on, and intermediate values for settings between off and fully on.

RPi.GPIO currently has no support for hardware PWM.

If you have a problem with pigpio and Python a listing showing the problem will be useful.

Comment: Thanks Joan. The problem with pigpio is as I have stated in my question: as soon as the DC is set to either 1 or 0, any value I send >1 results in fully on

Comment: I would need to see the code you are using as what you describe is not what happens, so either the code is wrong or your wiring is wrong or the backlight does not work as you think.

Comment: I don't think either the code or the wiring is wrong but I have updated my question to include the code.  It seems to me to be a pigpio bug or some lower level problem

Comment: I have run that code and it works fine.  I have also tried range(0,200) and range(200,0,-1) and they work fine as well.  The PWM continues to cycle correctly as can be seen using piscope.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it should work but it doesn't so don't know where to dig deeper to find the issue.  It must be a driver issue somewhere...

Comment: I have done used piscine now and can also see that the pin is doing what it should so it could be an issue with the LED driver. Thanks

Comment: So, I am using the TI driver [here] (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61165.pdf?ts=1594206932274&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). Am I right in thinking that by dimming to zero (or strangely 1) I am activating EasyScale?  If so, can you give me an idea on the complexity of writing a script to send the EasyScale commands?  I had a quick try using `wave_add_serial` etc. but no dice.  Looking at the pigpio examples, it looks quite in depth to just send a couple of nibbles, is that correct?

Comment: Interesting chip.  I'm sure you could use pigpio to program the one wire interface but I haven't the time to spare at the moment.  I suggest you use hardware PWM with pigpio at a higher frequency as you are using GPIO 18.  Try the Python [hardware_PWM()](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM) method.  Choose a frequency of say 10000 to prevent the chip entering one wire mode.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll give it a go.  Just to clarify: Do you mean that with the frequency at 10000, I would keep the duty cycle just above zero so you didn't see it but the chip would still not trigger EasyScale?  Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: I think so.  You may be able to set it to 0% (0) and 100% (1000000) as they shouldn't trigger the 160µs timeout either.  You will have to experiment.

Comment: OK, great, now it works.  I don't really understand how.  Even if I set to 0% for a few seconds and then back to another level, it works. But surely 0% is effectively Low and Easyscale should then trigger. Anyway, thanks

Comment: I think the trigger is less than a millisecond high then more than 160µs low.

Comment: I just don't quite understand how the higher frequency avoids this :/

Comment: Is there any reason that `get_pwm_dutycycle` after changing the duty cycle consistently gives three of the old value, a zero and then finally the new value?

Comment: Add a script which shows the problem as a NEW question and I'll have a look.